# Setting Max Width for an HTML email in Outlook - Why is it different than Gmail?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, mailchimp

I've been working to design an HTML email, and for some reason it looks great in MailChimp/Chrome/GMail, but in Outlook the columns are stretched and look horrible (see screenshots). I'm not great with HTML, and I've tried to changing several max-width parameters to 600px instead of 100%, without success.

I'd like the email to always be 600px wide.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Web View]

^How it looks in Chrome/Gmail

[image: Outlook View]

^How it looks in Outlook (top blue part is 600px, while the rest is stretched)

Here is the HTML code I'm working with:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #outlook a{
            padding:0;
        }
        body{
            width:600 !important;
        }
        .ReadMsgBody{
            width:100%;
        }
        .ExternalClass{
            width:100%;
        }
        body{
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        }
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        img{
            height:auto;
            line-height:100%;
            outline:none;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #backgroundTable{
            height:100% !important;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            width:100% !important;
        }
        body,#backgroundTable{
            background-color:#314A66;
        }
        h1,.h1{
            color:#FFFFFF;
            display:block;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:26px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            text-align:center;
        }
        h2,.h2{
            color:#0E385F;
            display:block;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:22px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            text-align:left;
        }
        h3,.h3{
            color:#0E385F;
            display:block;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            text-align:left;
        }
        h4,.h4{
            color:#0E385F;
            display:block;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            text-align:left;
        }
        #templatePreheader{
            background-color:#36C0CC;
        }
        .preheaderContent div{
            color:#CCCCCC;
            font-family:Lucida Sans,Lucida;
            font-size:10px;
            line-height:110%;
            text-align:left;
        }
        .preheaderContent div a:link,.preheaderContent div    a:visited,.preheaderContent div a .yshortcuts {
            color:#EEEEEE;
            font-weight:normal;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        #templateHeader{
            background-color:#36C0CC;
            border-bottom:0;
        }
        .headerContent div{
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight:normal;
            line-height:100%;
            padding-top:20px;
            padding-right:20px;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            padding-left:10px;
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align:top;
        }
        .headerContent div a:link,.headerContent div a:visited,.headerContent div a .yshortcuts {
            color:#336699;
            font-weight:normal;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .headerContent div img{
            height:auto;
            max-width:600px;
        }
        #templateContainer,.bodyContent{
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        #templateBody{
            border:0px none #10263F;
        }
        .bodyContent div,#social div{
            color:#505050;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:12px;
            line-height:150%;
        }
        .bodyContent div{
            text-align:justify;
        }
        .bodyContent div a:link,.bodyContent div a:visited,.bodyContent div a .yshortcuts ,#social div a:link,#social div a:visited{
            color:#336699;
            font-weight:normal;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .bodyContent div img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
            max-width:360px;
        }
        #social{
            padding-top:20px;
            padding-right:20px;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            padding-left:20px;
        }
        #social div{
            text-align:center;
        }
        #social div img{
            max-width:560px;
        }
        #templateSidebar{
            background-color:#accb50;
            border-left:0px dotted;
        }
        .sidebarContent div{
            color:#ffffff;
            font-family:Lucida Sans,Lucida;
            font-size:11px;
            line-height:150%;
            text-align:justify;
        }
        .sidebarContent div a:link,.sidebarContent div a:visited,.sidebarContent div a .yshortcuts {
            color:#336699;
            font-weight:normal;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .sidebarContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto !important;
            margin-bottom:10px !important;
        }
        #templateFooter{
            background-color:#36C0CC;
            border-top:2px solid #111111;
        }
        .footerContent div{
            color:#CCCCCC;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:10px;
            line-height:125%;
            text-align:left;
        }
        .footerContent div a:link,.footerContent div a:visited,.footerContent div a .yshortcuts {
            color:#EEEEEE;
            font-weight:normal;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .footerContent img{
            display:inline;
        }
        #utility{
            background-color:#36C0CC;
            border:0;
        }
        #utility div{
            text-align:center;
        }
        #monkeyRewards img{
            max-width:190px;
        }
        body,#backgroundTable{
            background-color:#ffffff;
        }
        h1,.h1{
            color:#ffffff;
            text-align:left;
            font-family:Lucida Sans,Lucida;
            line-height:110%;
        }
        .footerContent div a:link,.footerContent div a:visited,.footerContent div a .yshortcuts{
            color:#4D4C4C;
        }
        .bodyContent div,#social div{
            font-family:Lucida Sans,Lucida;
            font-size:11px;
            color:#545454;
            line-height:150%;
        }
        #templateContainer,.bodyContent{
            background-color:#E2E2E2;
        }
</style></head>
    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #ffffff;width: 600 !important;">
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #ffffff;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <!-- // Begin Template Preheader \\ -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templatePreheader" style="background-color: #36C0CC;">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent">

                                    <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top">
                                                <div style="color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 10px;line-height: 110%;text-align: left;"><a href="www.scandit.com" target="_blank" style="color: #EEEEEE;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img align="left" alt="" height="57" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/3c1958ec76b5e1d93c32cf088/files/scandit_logo_white_wtag2.png" style="width: 147px;height: 57px;float: left;border-width: 0px;border-style: solid;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" width="147"></a> </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|* -->
                                            <td valign="top" width="190">
                                                <div style="color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 10px;line-height: 110%;text-align: left;">
                                                    Is this email not displaying correctly?<br><a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" target="_blank" style="color: #EEEEEE;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">View it in your browser</a>.
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- *|END:IF|* -->
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Module: Standard Preheader \ -->

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- // End Template Preheader \\ -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer" style="background-color: #E2E2E2;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- // Begin Template Header \\ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader" style="background-color: #36C0CC;border-bottom: 0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="headerContent">
                                                <div style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;padding-top: 20px;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 10px;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;"><span style="font-size:24px;"><strong>&nbsp;Howdy!</strong><br></span></div>
               <div id="_com_1" uage="JavaScript" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify; padding-left: 20px;">
                Welcome!<br><br>

                <br></div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Template Header \\ -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- // Begin Template Body \\ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody" style="border: 0px none #10263F;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" style="background-color: #E2E2E2;">

                                                            <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Content \\ -->
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                                        <div style="color: #545454;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;"><div style="text-align: left;color: #545454;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;">
    <div style="color: #545454;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;">
        <div style="color: #545454;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;">
                <strong>Features</strong><br>
                <hr>

                </div>
                <ul>

                </ul>


                &nbsp;</div>

                <hr>
                &nbsp;<br>
                <center><FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="https://SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT">
</FORM></center>
                &nbsp;<br>
                &nbsp;<br>
                SAMPLE TEXT 
                <br>

                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <!-- // End Module: Standard Content \\ -->

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- // Begin Sidebar \\  -->
                                            <td valign="top" width="300" id="templateSidebar" style="background-color: #accb50;border-left: 0px dotted;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="00">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" class="sidebarContent" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:0;">
                                                                        <div style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;"><h4 class="h4" style="color: #0E385F;display: block;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;">

<span style="color:#fff0f5;">Getting Started</span></h4>
<hr>
<div style="text-align: left;color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;">
    <strong><span style="font-size:12px;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 240, 245); ">
    <ul>
                <li>Barcode Scanner SDK Documentation
                <ul>
                </ul>
                &nbsp;<br>
                SAMPLE TEXTSAMPLE TEXTSAMPLE TEXT <a href="" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">FAQs</a> or <a href="mailto:SAMPLETEXT.com" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">contact us</a>.<br>

    <h4 style="color: #0E385F;display: block;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;">
    <br><br>

    <span style="color:#fff0f5;">Get in Touch</span></h4>
<hr>
SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT<br>
<h4 style="color: #0E385F;display: block;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;">
    <br><br>

    <span style="color:#fff0f5;">Connect with us</span></h4>
<hr>
</div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <!-- // Begin Module: Social Block with Icons \\ -->
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">
                                                                            <tr mc:hideable="hideable_1" mchideable="hideable_1">
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" width="16">
                                                                                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/sfs_icon_facebook.png" style="margin: 0 !important;height: auto !important;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;margin-bottom: 10px !important;">
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                                    <div style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;"><div style="text-align: left;color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;">
    <span style="font-size:11px;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Scandit/127334280653842" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">Friend us on Facebook</a></span></div>
</div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr mc:hideable="hideable_2" mchideable="hideable_2">
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" width="16">
                                                                                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/sfs_icon_twitter.png" style="margin: 0 !important;height: auto !important;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;margin-bottom: 10px !important;">
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                                    <div style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/scandit" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">Follow us on Twitter</a> </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr mc:hideable="hideable_3" mchideable="hideable_3">
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" width="16">
                                                                                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/27aac8a65e64c994c4416d6b8/images/sfs_icon_rss.1.png" style="margin: 0 !important;height: auto !important;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;margin-bottom: 10px !important;">
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                                    <div style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;"><a href="http://www.scandit.com/blog" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">Read our blog</a> </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr mc:hideable="hideable_4" mchideable="hideable_4">
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" width="16">
                                                                                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/sfs_icon_forward.png" style="margin: 0 !important;height: auto !important;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;margin-bottom: 10px !important;">
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                                    <div style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: justify;"><div style="text-align: left;color: #ffffff;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;">
    <a href="*|FORWARD|*" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">Sign up for our newsletter</a></div>
</div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <!-- // End Module: Social Block with Icons \\ -->



                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- // End Sidebar \\ -->
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" valign="middle" id="social" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;">
                                                <div style="color: #545454;font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">follow on Twitter</a> | <a href="" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">friend on Facebook</a> | <a href="http://www.scandit.com/blog/" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">read our blog</a> | <a href="*|FORWARD|*" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">forward to a friend</a>&nbsp; </div>
                                                <center><em>SAMPLE TEXTSAMPLE  <a href="" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;">SAMPLE TEXT</a>.</em></center>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Template Body \\ -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- // Begin Template Footer \\ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateFooter" style="background-color: #36C0CC;border-top: 2px solid #111111;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="footerContent">

                                                <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Footer \\ -->
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" width="350">
                                                            <div style="color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 10px;line-height: 125%;text-align: left;">
                                                                <em>Copyright &copy; *|CURRENT_YEAR|* *|LIST:COMPANY|*, All rights reserved.</em>
                                                                <br>
                                                                *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|*
                                                                *|LIST:DESCRIPTION|*
                                                                <br>
                                                                <strong>Our mailing address is:</strong>
                                                                <br>
                                                                *|HTML:LIST_ADDRESS_HTML|*
                                                                <br>
                                                                *|END:IF|*
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td valign="top" width="190" id="monkeyRewards">
                                                            <div style="color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 10px;line-height: 125%;text-align: left;">
                                                                *|IF:REWARDS|* *|HTML:REWARDS|* *|END:IF|*
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" valign="middle" id="utility" style="background-color: #36C0CC;border: 0;">
                                                            <div style="color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 10px;line-height: 125%;text-align: center;">
                                                                &nbsp; <a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" style="color: #4D4C4C;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">view email in browser</a>*|END:IF|*&nbsp;
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Footer \\ -->

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Template Footer \\ -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's best practice for emails to use table-based layouts and inline-styling. If you are using MailChimp's templating system to construct this email, the CSS styles you define will be made automatically in-line when it sends out. You should still, however use a table-based layout.

Example:

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #36C0CC" colspan="2">Blue Section</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: gray">Gray Section</td>
        <td style="background: #accb50">Green Section</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could mimick it with an [Outlook conditional tag](https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/5525752). You simply sandwich the div you apply the max-width to. with it.

```
<!--[if mso]>
 <center>
 <table><tr><td width="580">
<![endif]-->

 <div style="max-width:580px; margin:0 auto;">

 <p>This text will be centered and constrained to 580 pixels even on Outlook which does not support max-width CSS</p>

 </div>
<!--[if mso]>
 </td></tr></table>
 </center>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgotten the `px` after 600 in

```
 body{
       width:600 !important;
        }
```

So it should works

```
 body{
            width:600px !important;
        }
```

And also it's not good to set body again, what you have done two times.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Thanks for the catch though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this max-width fluid example. It uses a combination of max-width, Outlook conditionals and a media query for Outlook '11 (which is webkit based and can't be targeted with Outlook conditionals):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Client-specific Styles - last updated 18 Feb 2014 */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    a:active, a:visited, a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: #005288 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
    .link1 a, .link1 a:active, .link1 a:visited {color: #005288 !important; text-decoration: none;}
    .link2 a, .link2 a:active, .link2 a:visited {color: #FFFFFE !important; text-decoration: none;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { .maxW { width:600px !important; } }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#252525" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="top">
<![endif]-->
<table width="100%" class="maxW" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">


<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: auto;">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="padding:30px;">
      Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</td></tr></table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: This works but end  tag  needs to be moved  </td></tr></table>

</td></tr></table><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--></body></html>